# Return integer value as result of comparison operator in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

### Background

In MySQL, you can get the result of comparison operator as integer value like below.
This feature is useful when you want to sort the result of SELECT with weighed matching score.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Table1 (`value1` int, `value2` int, `value3` int);

INSERT INTO Table1 (`value1`, `value2`, `value3`)
VALUES             (1, 2, 3),
                   (2, 4, 6),
                   (3, 6, 9);

select value1, value2, value3, 1*(value1=1), 2*(value2=4), 3*(value3=9) from table1;
->  1   2   3   1   0   0
    2   4   6   0   2   0
    3   6   9   0   0   3
```

### Problem

In PostgreSQL, the result of comparison operator is boolen.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Table1 ("value1" int, "value2" int, "value3" int);

INSERT INTO Table1 ("value1", "value2", "value3")
VALUES             (1, 2, 3),
                   (2, 4, 6),
                   (3, 6, 9);

select value1, value2, value3, value1=1, value2=4, value3=9 from table1;
->  1   2   3   true    false   false
    2   4   6   false   true    false
    3   6   9   false   false   true
```

And you will get an error if you try to convert boolean value to integer:

```sql
select value1, value2, value3, 1*(value1=1), 2*(value2=4), 3*(value3=9) from table1;
ERROR: operator does not exist: integer * boolean Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 33
```

### Question

How can I get integer value as result of comparison operator in PostgreSQL?

Comment: "*the result of comparison operator is boolean*" - yes of course it is. What else could it be. MySQL's behaviour is wrong, not Postgres'

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My question was solved. Anyway, is there any statement about the comparison in SELECT clause in the SQL standards? I feel it is too different between RDBMS implementations for the standard. See: http://satob.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/11/15/002554

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast boolean to integer:

```
select value1, value2, value3, 1*(value1=1)::int, 2*(value2=4)::int, 3*(value3=9)::int 
from table1;

 value1 | value2 | value3 | ?column? | ?column? | ?column? 
--------+--------+--------+----------+----------+----------
      1 |      2 |      3 |        1 |        0 |        0
      2 |      4 |      6 |        0 |        2 |        0
      3 |      6 |      9 |        0 |        0 |        3
(3 rows)
```